# Any ways to find the column having most uniformly distributed values

Tags: sql-server, uniform-distribution

I am novice in the SQL Server and mathematical functions, in general.

My ultimate goal is to import data from SQL Server onto Hadoop using Sqoop.

The constraints :

1. There are aplenty schema, thereby, hundreds of tables to be imported
2. The developers knowing about the tables are unavailable for now

To get optimal import performance, it is necessary to use **a column(need NOT be a part of the PK but desirable) which has it's values evenly/uniformly distributed**, please see the below example for elaboration :

Sample data from the table PK(DateDimensionId,DriverDimensionId,VehicleDimensionId) and **no. of rows is 1203769164**:

[image: sample data]

To get an idea about the distinct values of the PK columns, I executed :

```
select COUNT_BIG(distinct DriverDimensionId) cnt_DriverDimensionId
  from [VehicleData].[DateVehicleDriverAggregate];
```

**1581023**

```
select COUNT_BIG(distinct DateDimensionId) cnt_DateDimensionId
  from [VehicleData].[DateVehicleDriverAggregate];
```

**46930**

```
select COUNT_BIG(distinct VehicleDimensionId) cnt_VehicleDimensionId
  from [VehicleData].[DateVehicleDriverAggregate];
```

**218041**

but still, I do not have an idea about which of the above 3(OR other columns in the table) have uniform values e.g if I consider **DateDimensionId**, it has 46930 distinct values but are they evenly distributed in ranges like (2011040300, 2012040300), (2012040300, 2013040300) and so on.

Is there some mathematical function or something that I can use to decide which column to use ?

Comment: you can try group by clause in each column and find the distribution of that column for each distinct values                                                  select COUNT(DateDimensionId) as cnt_DateDimensionId,DateDimensionId
  from [VehicleData].[DateVehicleDriverAggregate] group by DateDimensionId;

Comment: is your SQL server background architecture is MPP?

Comment: I am just having a read-only access to SQL Server and I don't have the knowledge of the architecture that you are asking about :(